# Running migrations works locally but not on Travis CI

Tags: django, python-2.7, migration, travis-ci

I have a project in Django 1.8 and I'm starting to use Travis CI, but I have a problem that I cannot solve.

When I perform test locally, by `python manage.py test`, it works fine and there is no problem at running migrations. However, when the same command is executed by Travis, it applies well all migrations except one.

The error trace is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "EntHub/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 74, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 90, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 210, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 166, in setup_databases
    **kwargs
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 370, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 368, in create_test_db
    test_flush=True,
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 221, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 201, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 469, in alter_field
    return self._alter_many_to_many(model, old_field, new_field, strict)
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 785, in _alter_many_to_many
    old_field.rel.through._meta.get_field(old_field.m2m_field_name()),
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 554, in get_field
    raise FieldDoesNotExist('%s has no field named %r' % (self.object_name, field_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Account_following has no field named None
```

These are the model and the migrations:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Account

class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    avatar = models.URLField(blank=True)
    following = models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=False, related_name="followers", blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user.username)
```

**0001_initial.py** *(OK)*

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
from django.conf import settings


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Account',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('birth', models.DateField(blank=True)),
                ('text', models.TextField(blank=True)),
                ('avatar', models.URLField(blank=True)),
                ('user', models.OneToOneField(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

**0002_auto_20161116_1512.py** *(OK)*

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('main', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='account',
            name='birth',
            field=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True),
        ),
    ]
```

**0003_account_following.py** *(OK)*

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('main', '0002_auto_20161116_1512'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='account',
            name='following',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(related_name='_account_following_+', to='main.Account', blank=True),
        ),
    ]
```

**0004_auto_20170119_1151.py** *(fails)*

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('main', '0003_account_following'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='account',
            name='following',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(related_name='followers', to='main.Account', blank=True),
        ),
    ]
```

I further provide my file `.travis.yml`:

```
language: python
python:
  - "2.7"
env:
  - DJANGO_VERSION=1.8
services:
  - postgresql
addons:
  postgresql: "9.3"
install:
  - pip install -q Django==$DJANGO_VERSION
  - pip install psycopg2
before_script:
  - psql -c "CREATE USER enthub WITH PASSWORD 'enthub';" -U postgres
  - psql -c "ALTER USER enthub CREATEDB;" -U postgres
script:
  - python EntHub/manage.py test --verbosity=2
```

`enthub/enthub` are the credentials of database in `settings.py`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be a Django issue related to alter field migrations of many to many self-realted fields, but it's strange that it only appears on Travis. In the end, because the project is still under development, I have decided to delete the migrations `0003_account_following.py` and `0004_auto_20170119_1151.py` and run again the command `python manage.py makemigrations`. Now all works fine, but I have had to reset the database.